# How to remove duplicate string without removing blank lines? C#

Tags: c#, string

I am using a built in function to remove duplicate lines but function is considering blank rows also as duplicates. Could anyone help me getting where I am mistaken?  Here is my code:

```
 protected void Remove_Duplicate_Lines_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
       (Remove_Empty_Lines_CheckBox_id.Checked)      // Remove Blank Rows

         String input_txt = "A \n\n B \n \n B \n\n C \n\n C \n\n D \n\n E";

                string[] distinctLines = input_txt.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None).Distinct().ToArray(); 
                txt_output.InnerText = string.Join("\r\n", distinctLines);}
```

Example:
[image]

Example 2 (undesired)

[image]

Comment: I don't think the option new string[] { Environment.NewLine } will split the input. You may want to use new string[] { "\n"} instead

Comment: You had examples of the expected and actual output, but you removed them. I think they were useful, as I can't currently follow the question: your `input_txt` doesn't have any blank rows in it.

Comment: consider `input_text` as a multi-line string which has blank lines/white spaces as well.

Comment: I ran your example input, and it doesn't match your "actual output": https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mi8k4w

Comment: So in your example. where there are two "B"s, there are then two empty lines before the next unique item -  "C" -  but in your expected output there is only one line between B and C. What rules should be used to collapse multiples like this? Should they be collapsed to one blank line?

Comment: This is not only finding the answer, but also testing our ability to interpret the requirements. Not very clear because example code and example output are out-of-sync.

Comment: I pardon. I have editted code

Comment: So when the input is `A\n\n\n\n\n\nB\n\n\n\n\n\nB\n\n\n\C` what's the required output? Or is there always exactly one empty line between inputs?

Comment: It is not clear whether duplicates should only be removed when they are consecutive. So, should `AABBAAABB` be recuced to `ABAB` or to `AB`?.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems, mostly with your split.  You compose `input__txt` to contain "\n" but later try to split on `Environment.NewLine`, which itself is "\n\r".  Thus the split won't occur as you desire.

Let's consider this:

`String input_txt = "A \n A \n B \n D \n A \n E";`

Secondly, even if you split on "\n", the result will have 2 entries for A, namely "A" and " A ", because you have not trimmed anything.

My suggestion would be to split on more than 1 pattern AND remove empty entries.  Either you would need to also Trim() each item, or else just add " " in the split pattern.  The final result will not have any blank lines between entries.  To control blank lines later when you need them, do this yourself when you need to output.

```
String input_txt = "A \n A \n B \n D \n A \n E";

string[] distinctLines = input_txt.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine, "\n", " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                    .Select(x => x.Trim())
                                    .Distinct()
                                    .ToArray();
txt_output.InnerText = string.Join(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine, distinctLines);
```

This will output:

```
A

B

D

E
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a comprehensive answer. But it won't work for different type of inputs. Please have a look on other examples

Comment: `Distinct()` is not guaranteed to keep the order of the elements.

Comment: @NineBerry I know the documentation says so. But it yields the elements in the order as the source, and has done so since linq was introduces. This might of course change in an upcoming version. An alternative is to use `GroupBy` and than only use the `key` returned. `GroupBy` _does_ guarantee the order.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Distinct()` will not work here, because `Distinct()` is not guaranteed to keep the order of elements. Use a traditional approach: A loop and some variables to remember the state.

Use a `HashSet` to remember the lines you have seen before and a `bool` variable to remember whether there was an empty line in the input since the last time we output something to the output list.

```
string inputText = textBox1.Text;
List<string> outputLines = new List<string>();

// Use appropriate String Comparer based on your requirements
HashSet<string> seenLines = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
bool seenEmptyLine = false;

string[] lines = inputText.Split('\n');

foreach(string line in lines)
{
    string trimmedLine = line.Trim();

    if(trimmedLine == "")
    {
        // When we see an empty line, we remember that we have seen one
        seenEmptyLine = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // When we see a non-empty line, we add it only when we have not seen it before
        if(seenLines.Contains(trimmedLine))
        {
            // Seen line before, skip it
        }
        else
        {
            // Remember we have seen this line
            seenLines.Add(trimmedLine);

            // if we have seen an empty line since adding last line,
            // add empty line
            if(seenEmptyLine)
            {
                seenEmptyLine = false;
                outputLines.Add("");
            }

            outputLines.Add(trimmedLine);
        }
    }

}

string outputText = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, outputLines);

textBox2.Text = outputText;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such an comprehensive answer. Its working perfectly. However  I want to make it case insensitive as well. ToLower() formats whole text. Any other possibility?

Comment: I've found it.  (seenLines.Contains(trimmedLine, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))

Comment: @Emmy You can specify the comparer to use while creating the Hashset. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I am editing your answer as there is a small issue that it cosiders 3 consecutive white spaces as single space hence removing other 2 spaces. So there is no need of `bool seenEmptyLine = false;`

Comment: Another problem is: it always removes very first whites-space.. For example: if my input is like` " \n A \n B \n D \n A \n E";`. Output should be:  " \n A \n B \n D \n E";` But the actual output is: ` " A \n B \n D \n E";`

Comment: @Emmy Example 2 in the question has two empty lines become one. Editing other people's answers is considered rude. You need to make your requirements clearer.

Comment: acknowledged. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to implement your own EqualityComparer:

```
void Main()
{
    var str = "A\nA\n\n\nB\n\nD\nA\n\nE";

    var before = str.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    var after = before.Distinct(new MyComparer());
}

public class MyComparer : EqualityComparer<string>
{
    public override bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        if(x == "" && y == "")
            return false;
        return x.Equals(y);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but here Dump() function is raising error 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Dump' and no extension method 'Dump' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"  Linq is included

Comment: Dump is just an extension to write it to console. Just remove that.